# Word for when: two people are attempting to use a doorway at the same time

Tags: meaning

Word for when: two people are attempting to use a doorway at the same time.
I'm sure this is an all too common phenomena we have all witnessed. Either you are trying to exit/enter someplace when at that exact moment someone is trying to do the same so you are stuck in a game of who goes first, until someone initiates and someone cedes.

This came up as I  working on actually documenting this phenemonon. I happen to be a student studying sociology, ie people interacting with other people, when i realized there is no word for this phenomenon. I thought how could this be! Surely the internet must know! But alas here I am.

I will surely cite anyone who can answer my quandary in my paper!

Thanks

Comment: Isn’t that a “door jam”? :-)

Comment: I've heard "corridor dance" for a similar situation  but surprisingly don't recall hearing the nice (because it's alliterative) doorway dance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider ***doorway stalemate***, which is used [here](http://www.salary.com/How-to-Deal-with-a-Doorway-Stalemate/) to mean a situation where there are people on *opposite* sides of a door, each waiting for the other to enter first.

You could easily use it to describe the situation where there are two people on the *same* side.

[Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=chivalrous+stalemate) also defines ***chivalrous stalemate*** as "When two people are trying to pass through a doorway and both insist that the other goes first." But this entry doesn't have many upvotes.

[Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Canadian%20Standoff) also uses the situation you describe as an example of a ***Canadian Standoff***.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the *indisijig*, which is when two people fail to pass in an aisle. It was coined by a comedian, but I don't remember which one.